# i wanted to make a simple program in c language for calculation of area of circle by taking input of radius from user

Tags: c, scanf

i am not getting the required result, instead i am getting garbage value
please help me finding mistake in code

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int radius;
float pi=3.14;
printf("Type radius of circle \n");
scanf("%d", &radius);
printf("Area of circle is %f \n", pi*radius*radius );

return 0;}
```

Comment: What is your input, actual output, and expected output?

Comment: Seems to work ok for me: https://ideone.com/WrCKPw

Comment: "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.928]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\CODES\C tutorial> area_of_circle.exe
Type radius of circle 
3.14
Area of circle is 0.000000 

D:\CODES\C tutorial> "     This is what i am getting in terminal

Comment: For me it's working fine. I compiled on GDB online compiler and I got the correct results. You can try it yourself here: [https://onlinegdb.com/HkHGUsnId](https://onlinegdb.com/HkHGUsnId)

Comment: You're entering `3.14`? You know that an `int` won't hold that, right? Nevertheless, I get `28.260001` with the code you've given. Check the return value of the `scanf`. It should be `1`.

Comment: THANKS FRED LARSON... did a awful mistake

Comment: You're welcome! So glad I never make mistakes. ;-) But what solved your problem?

Comment: While we are at it: I know it's taught at almost every C course this way, but it's a good practice to avoid `scanf` in your code. For more details about how to do it without `scanf` you can read this article: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)